# wordpress theme backend admin only

Tags: plugins, theme-development, themes

Does anyone know of a theme that completely removes all uses and aspects of the frontend. So the sole use of the site will be in the admin section. to use as a portal for something like a school or internal government uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three things (if i understood your needs correctly):

- Adjust the admin menu items [@MikeSchinkel Gist](https://gist.github.com/780709)
- [The Backpress project](http://backpress.org/)
- ...or simply [`wp_redirect();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect) on login and [offer only a login screen in your index.php template](http://digwp.com/2010/12/login-register-password-code/).

Comment: Hmmm I looked at backpress, very interesting. have you or anybody else used this?

Comment: No. I thought about it for a project, but it's really only a base. You'll have to define a whole load of stuff (starting at user handling). If you want to just get your stuff done, i'd recommend to go the standard wp-way with wp_redirect and a login-template only theme.

Answer (score 1):

The [Registered Users Only plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/registered-users-only/) will block all access to the front end to users who are not registered.  Also check out [Bill Erickson's Twentyten CRM theme](http://www.billerickson.net/twentyten-crm/) that was built specifically as a private use theme.

Comment: Cool, didn’t knew that theme.

Answer (score 0):

You could very easily create a theme that just acted as a landing page, with a link to the admin area.

To create a valid theme, all you need is a style.css with the appropriate mark up ([see codex here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Theme_Stylesheet)) and an index.php. The index.php needs not contain any actual PHP, and you can create a holding page using just HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You could also completely block the access to the front site with a .htaccess rule.